# how to check packet flooding in bridging

Tags: testing, networking, ethernet, bridging

I am a newbie in networking and learned about bridging concepts .I have a device which functions as bridge which works in transparent mode and filter mode.In the latter mode , whenever the packet is received to Ethernet port (which is bind to bridge ports of bridge) it floods to other Ethernet ports except the received one through bridging, If the mac address is not learned .How can i ensure this ? can anyone suggest a method to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Every Ethernet switch you can find is a bridge. It learns MAC addresses from ingress frames and uses this MAC table for efficient forwarding. In the unlikely event of an unknown destination address is mimicks a repeater and outputs the frame to all ports but the one it was received from.

If you connect several computers with a bridge/switch and run a packet capture on all of them you'll see that you won't see traffic between two computers on a third computer. Some - broadcast - traffic - will show up on all of them, e.g. when you start a connection and ARP is requesting the destination MAC address for the destination IP address.